# Remove only the sub element from a find

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to delete only the subdocument found at the bottom of my search parameters?

Let's say I have this query :

```
const diagnostics = await Diagnostic.find({
      'stepListings.steps.apps': { "$elemMatch": { '_id': "5ed1439ffc2b530012deafd3" } } 
});
```

It will give me all `Diagnostic` items that fit the following requirements (one of it's steplistings, has at least one of the steps that has an app with and _id of "5ed1439ffc2b530012deafd3") so I can get multiple Diagnostics here. If I remove with this query filter, it will delete from the root document (the whole Diagnostic in this case) Is there a way to remove only the very bottom of the search (the app within the steps in this case) so that I keep the Diagnostic, it's steplistings and it's steps but loose the app with the desired _id.

I can do the thing in the long way by looping through diagnostics, then steplistings...steps..apps and splice the app from there but it is a lot of looping for something that can probably be done in a one liner.

Comment: Does [db.collection.deleteMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/#delete-operations) solve your problem?

Comment: Top and bottom are too vague. Do you want to **update** all documents in `diagnostic` collection so that it's `stepListings.steps.apps` array will have no apps with the given _id?

Comment: @AlexBlex Yeah I figured. I want to find all diagnostic documents with a stepListings.steps.apps that has the given _id. If I find it, I want the `apps` to be removed. Nothing else in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your `stepListings`, `steps` and `apps` are all arrays, you can use [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) with [The all positional operator $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) to solve the problem. Something like:

```
Diagnostic.updateMany(
  {'stepListings.steps.apps._id': "5ed1439ffc2b530012deafd3" },
  {
    $pull: {
      'stepListings.$[].steps.$[].apps': {_id: "5ed1439ffc2b530012deafd3"}
    }
  }
);
```